# Accessing java class files in Parent Directory

Tags: java, directory

I am trying to work with directories and how they work with Java but cannot find a way to create an instance of an Object that is located inside the Parent directory

MainFolder

- CreateMe.class
- SubFolder

  - RunMe.class

My goal is to be able to execute RunMe.class and for it to instantiate CreateMe which is located in its parent Directory

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Looks, it is in Default package. RunMe Class should have priviledge to instantiate CreateMe class

Comment: How would i go about packaging? Never had to do them before

Answer (score 0):

First advice would be use eclipse or Netbeans. In this way all the class files under src directory are accessible by one another.

for ex: 
 if you have CreateMe.java in com.task package and you your RunMe.class in com.task.sub package then RunMe.class will access CreateMe.java by importing it.

Second, if you are not going to use eclipse or netbeans you should give supporting class files folder location in compile and run time. In this case, your class will look up class files available in supporting folder location as well.